# why Images are not shown in gallary

Tags: android, image, save

I am developing an app in which I have a more than 10 images. When I save those images to card then these images saved on card perfectly but not shown in gallary. After resarting the device, images apper in gallary. I used lot of methods but no results. So plz give me some solution. 
Here is code.

```
 File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
 String path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() + "/YourFolder/"; 
  File dir = new File(path); 
  if (!dir.exists()) { 
  if (dir.mkdirs()) {
   }
  }
  OutputStream outStream = null; 
   ///below Code String 
  strFileName=android.text.format.DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ssaa", new java.util.Date()).toString();
     File file = new File(path, strFileName+ ".png");

      try { 
           outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bbicon.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream); 
        outStream.flush();
         outStream.close();
         } catch(Exception e) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method like this:

```
void doScanFile(String fileName) {
        String[] filesToScan = {fileName};

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, filesToScan, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    public void onScanCompleted(String filePath, Uri uri) {
                        mediaFileScanComplete(filePath, uri);
                    }
                });
}

void mediaFileScanComplete(String mediaFilePath, Uri mediaFileUri) {

   //Save this infromation to fiels if you need them
    _lastMediaFilePath = mediaFilePath;
    _lastMediaFileUri = mediaFileUri;
}
```

After file saved call it with your filename - doScanFile(file.toString());

Comment: Have you declared the two fields `_lastMediaFilePath` and `_lastMediaFileUri´? If yes, what kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Thanx sir for your cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative way you could add the images individually upon creation with the following line:

```
context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(outputFile)));
```

With outputFile being your image.